# No panels, launcher, etc visible on desktop

Tags: unity

My first time trying to use Ubuntu. I clean installed the Ubuntu 12.10-beta2 on an old Dell Dimension 4600 today. Install seemed to go fine, but after restarting and entering the requested passwords I'm taken to a purple screen with no panels, launchers or anything else--just a purple screen. I'm able to access the terminal from the screen with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>, but I'm not sure at this point in my Linux training how to search for errors. Also have no Internet connection (I'm typing this on a mac), but I'll have to deal with that later. Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I ran the tail -f /var/log/syslog command at kmassada's suggestion and it seems to be riddled with hundreds of errors. I installed from a usb flash drive, not sure if that's part of the problem. Would you suggest reinstalling the beta version or perhaps try a different one? Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Those are the symptoms of [bug 1039155](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-distro-priority/+bug/1039155), which was marked fixed by an update in Quantal today.  Update and try it.

> compiz (1:0.9.8.4-0ubuntu2) quantal; urgency=low
>
> - debian/patches/unity_support_test.patch:
>
>   - force llvmpipe in the unity profile if we are in the grey zone, meaning:
>       the card and drivers have opengl support, however, it doesn't met unity
>       requirements (opengl < 1.4, no vertex shaders support…). Thanks duflu
>       (LP: #1039155)
>
>     Note that we already discourage them to upgrade from precise to quantal
>       with a warning before the upgrade, however let's get a slow ui rather
>       than none on the iso as well.
>
>   -- Didier Roche  Tue, 09 Oct 2012 15:26:52 +0200

Update: the user who filed that bug has written: "Re-opening the bug as it is not fixed for me."  So this looks up in the air for now.

Comment: Sure. :)  If you find out, let us know whether the update helped much!

Answer (score 0):

For any errors in ubuntu, usually this command would help pin point if there was a major error. It is a way of viewing a snippet of your error log.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Also since you can bring up the terminal, my guess is, unity must have an issue. I recommend you run the following commands

first open the software properties window,

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

go to *other software* TAB, and enable the **Cannonical Partners** and the **source code**, and the **independent**, and their **source code**. Also in the *Ubuntu Software* TAB, **enable all the following sources**,

If the issue is that you've installed a buggy package, it will upgrade your system, with the latest fixes. [Ubuntu repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) talks about each, and what is their role. Since you running beta anyways, i'll recommend it. But you can read up and see if you want to keep them enabled after the final release. Close the window

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

reboot.

If error persist, we have to reset unity, from command line

install dconf-tools

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Reset Compiz and Unity

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

setsid unity
```

Comment: Seems to be riddled with errors. I installed from a usb drive, don't know if that was an issue or not. May be too much info, but here's what I got after running the first command:

Comment: I don't get to see your code, if it is pastie.org, just comment with the ID at the end of url.

Comment: http://pastie.org/5019380

Comment: hmm doesn't look familiar.. must be usb you still have plugged in, did you try the packages upgrade? and reboot?

Comment: Yes, but I can't connect to the internet yet and it looked like it needed a connection to download some of the upgrades. I may be better off uninstalling it and trying over. Do you think I should go with the beta version again?

Comment: Its worth the try. It doesn't take too long for a reinstall. this time establish the connection at install so you can get the latest packages

Comment: @Gene if I have answered your question please marked as solved. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help The software was reinstalled and everything seems to be working fine now. This is now solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution was running these command from tty1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>):

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at these links:
[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

this one solved my problem (i have Ubuntu 13.10):
[Unity completely broken after upgrade to 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204778/unity-completely-broken-after-upgrade-to-12-10/204784)