# Unity completely broken after upgrade to 12.10?

Tags: unity, 12.10

I am facing a very frustrating issue with my computer right now. I successfully upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10 this afternoon, but after the upgrade, the graphical user interface seems completely broken. To be more specific, **I can not get the Unity bar to appear on the right**.

I have tried many things, including (but not limited to) **purging and then reinstalling the fglrx drivers**, `apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`, `apt-get install --reinstall unity`, tried to **remove the Xorg and Compiz configurations**, **checked to see if the Ubuntu Unity wall was enabled (it was)** in `ccsm`, all to no avail.

Could someone help me troubleshoot and essentially fix this issue?

**NOTE:** This is the output when I try to enable unity via a terminal:

```
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
unity-panel-service: no process found
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: reset
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to load plugin: reset
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ccp
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ccp
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: composite
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: opengl
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  22
  Current serial number in output stream:  22
compiz (core) - Info: Unity is not supported by your hardware. Enabling software rendering instead (slow).
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: opengl
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin initScreen failed: opengl
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to start plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: opengl
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: decor
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: decor
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
compiz (decor) - Warn: requested a pixmap type decoration when compositing isn't available
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: imgpng
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: vpswitch
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: resize
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: resize
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: compiztoolbox
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: move
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: gnomecompat
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: mousepoll
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: Plugin init failed: wall
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to start plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: wall
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: regex
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: snap
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: Plugin init failed: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to start plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: unitymtgrabhandles
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: place
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: grid
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: grid
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: Plugin init failed: animation
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to start plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: animation
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: Plugin init failed: fade
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to start plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: fade
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: session
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: Plugin init failed: expo
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to start plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: expo
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: Plugin init failed: ezoom
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to start plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: ezoom
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: workarounds
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded.

compiz (core) - Error: Plugin init failed: scale
compiz (core) - Error: Failed to start plugin: scale
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: scale
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: it sounds like this issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers if you have a nvidia card

Comment: Nope I have an AMD 6870, and I have installed the fglrx driver

Comment: This fixed my problem Today (19 January 2012, Saturday).

http://askubuntu.com/questions/202574/desktop-does-not-show-when-i-installed-nvidia-drivers

Comment: I have thus far refused to upgrade to 12.10 but stuck with LTS. I had installed 12.10 on one machine and had to reinstall LTS on it because I had no time to deal with all the ideosyncracies of 12.10 or whatever Mark Shuttleworth decided to declare war on our common sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i see in log compiz plugin init failed i would try to reset compiz manager to default settings maybe it'll help

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwFG9XpdYEg
  http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-reset-unity-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal

Or else i recommend to completely* (with all settings*)remove unity via synaptic and reinstall it again or use terminal:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Think for yourself if is it usefull

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it provides the same errors as before.

Comment: maybe the issue is in these words in log :Unity is not supported by your hardware..Try to enable low graphic mode and see if it works. About this tweak here http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/make-unity-more-responsive-in-ubuntu.html otherwise for now i would recommend to install different desktop like gnome 3 or fallback.

Comment: I am only accepting this answer because it inspired me to install xfce via `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` which seemed to serve well as a work around until some time passes and I try unity again.

Comment: i tried my  best .. i posted own question and no one replied so i decided to help someone.These things i would do by myself in unity glitches.Sorry its not pro level.

Answer (score 6):

I had some hassle with the proprietary NVidia drivers too, but at some point was sure it was finally corrected, but Unity was still broken.

I also noted that using a guest account, Unity was displaying fine, so it was a per-user setting. This here helped:  `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` (had to reconfigure the docking bar but that's acceptable).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and it appeared that it was linked to my AMD graphic card's driver.

I fixed it following [this procedure](http://www.unixmen.com/ubuntu-12-10-and-amd-catalyst-problem-solved/). 
I used the 3rd-party repository created by Tomasz Makarewicz.

Basically, this procedure explains three ways to install the AMD Catalyst missing drivers. As it is well explain on the page, there is no point to copy the information here.

Hope it helps!

Comment: can you please tell me what system info says in system properties-graphic info after you installed makson96 package?For me it was vesa m98 so i dont know is it bad or not

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it fixed my problem. Also, I tried the script from the ati site and it did not work. I really had to go with the 3rd party repository option like you did.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem.  I used unity-reset tool that I found from another post here:

**From Git**
To install

```
git clone https://github.com/phanimahesh/unity-revamp.git
cd unity-revamp
chmod +x unity-reset.py
ln -s ./unity-reset.py /usr/bin/unity-reset
```

To run

```
unity-reset
```

**From Amith's PPA**
To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:amith/ubuntutools
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-reset
```

To use:

```
unity-reset
```

Comment: I did install it earlier on, from amith's ppa, but it didn't seem to help me.

Comment: Doesn't work. This is a problem with the drivers rather than unity itself.

Answer (score 3):

For cards newer than the 3XXX the best way to resolve this is to install the kernel headers.
First you need to revert to the original Xorg driver that does work. (right mouse click on the desktop and selecting "Change Desktop" get's you in the menu where you find "Software Sources")

It appears that the proprietary drivers need to be compiled to the kernel but can't due to missing headers.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

After that just install the proprietary driver you fancy.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

finally reboot your PC

This worked for me on ATI4200 (I've tried everything else but this worked...)

However, if something doesn't work out, you can always remove the repository and go back:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:makson96/fglrx
```

> [**source**](http://www.unixmen.com/ubuntu-12-10-and-amd-catalyst-problem-solved/)

Comment: Thank you very much! The fglrx available at repos screws up compositing (and not at all reducing power consumption as compared to the generic graphic driver). This worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the fglrx drivers (for ati cards)? In that case this is a known bug. Please go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/fglrx/+bug/1068661 and report that it affects you too (the option is near the top of the page).

You can remove the fglrx drivers and revert to the open source drivers (which should work) by following the instructions on http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx

If you have an old ati graphics card see Showpaths answer