# 13.04: Chaged graphic driver, lost unity

Tags: unity, drivers, ati, graphics

After changing my graphic driver to one of the options shown as proprietary, I lost unity (wallpaper shows, terminal can be opened with ctrl+t, but nothing else displays).

**My notebook: Dell Vostro 3560, Intel® Core™ i7-3612QM, AMD Radeon HD 7670M, 1 GB VRAM**

**What I already did is:**

- Reboot
- [Install fglrx-legacy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208346/ubuntu-12-10-shows-no-launcher-or-menu)
- Add UNITY_FORCE_START=1 to /etc/environment
- [sudo apt-get remove fglrx-*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210040/unity-does-not-start-after-installing-the-fglrx-drivers)
- [Reinstall the driver](http://www.techlw.com/2013/01/install-amd-ati-drivers-in-ubuntu.html) with sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy and ...fglrx-* (tried them all)

For the last one: "fglrx-installer" as mentioned in the link was not found.

**The Error:**

When I go to terminal (ctrl+alt+F1) and run the command unity, I get some hundred error lines reading like

```
Compiz (opengl) - Fatal: glXQueryExtensionsString is NULL for screen 0
```

**If it helps:**

```
lspci| grep VGA
```

returns

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core Processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thamas XT [Radeon HD 7670M]
```

**The question:**

How can I revert my change to a proprietary graphic driver without beeing able to open the drivers window I made the changes in?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I followed the proposed procedure, unfortunately I had no success, as there where multiple errors. Eventually someone is able to interpret them.

1)/etc/X11/xorgs.conf does not exist.

2)unitx-reset gives 50+ errors "dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changed to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus launch --autolaunch..."

3) installing fglrx from launchpad failed for dozens of unresolveable dependencies.

4) sudo apt-get install fglrx

**How can I get rid of all manually installed drivers and use the pre-installed ones that where shipped on the cd? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

Ok what I would do is:

Bring up a terminal window by pressing ctrl+alt+t or by going to crtl+alt+F2 and logging in to a text console there.
(press ctrl+alt+F7 to get back to the gui console)

sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers

sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot

See if things are looking better...

If not, get to a terminal again;
wget https://launchpad.net/~amith/+archive/ubuntutools/+build/3910667/+files/unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i unity-reset_0.1-8_all.deb
(or copy it from another computer to a usb stick and install it from there)

Then go into the gui console (CTRL+ALT+F7)
Get a terminal window (CTRL+ALT+T) or otherwise try using ALT+F2,
and type:
unity-reset
Wait for a couple of minutes while the script does its' thing.
Hopefully Unity will be recovered.

Then go here and download the latest fglrx package:
https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa/+packages and download your preferred fglrx package (I would avoid the beta one).

Then install it, restart and see if everything works.
If not, try running unity-reset again, and hopefully that will fix it. 
If the driver still messes things up, you could alternatively uninstall it and use the open source one, or try one of the fglrx drivers that are in the Ubuntu ppa. (sudo apt-get install fglrx) or (sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates)

Comment: Hello, thank you! (+1) I followed the procedure and updated my question with the results.