# No Unity or Sys tray?

Tags: 13.04

I have the same issue. Initial upgrade from 12.10 was a disaster and ended up having to reinstall off a fresh burnt cd. The result was a patchy workable 13.04 but applications seem to un install themselves at will and now I have lost the systray and unity munu bar. I am able to function through the cairo dock at present.
Also thought about booting into Gnome to see if that helped but it was not an option on the login screen. Instead of that or the Ubuntu login I had a Cairo login symbol consisting of a circle with CD in it!!
I am by no means a programmer but a jobbing user who up untill now has flown the flag for the Linux distro. I would love some idiot proof advice please.

Comment: I have the same issue and I think it may be becasue of incompatibility between the new compiz version and my ATI graphic card drivers. I'll try to solve and I'll tell. You can try on this way as well

Comment: Solved for me, I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install `dconf-editor`.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Start and goto: `com > canonical > unity > panel` and edit: `systray-witelist ['all']`

Comment: No he is saying that he **doesn't have a sys tray or unity** - I am currently having the same problem, in case someone knows the answer, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

If it is related to your ATI drivers you can find some options for your problem in that other question: [Unity completely broken after upgrade to 12.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204778/unity-completely-broken-after-upgrade-to-12-10)

I've solved it by:

Uninstalling older fglrx ATI drivers as in [here](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx)

Installing ATI legacy drivers from 3rd-party repository created by Tomasz Makarewicz

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:makson96/fglrx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install fglrx-legacy
```

For some error I had to reinstall Xorg but I suppose it is not necesary.

I had to force ATI configuration to be able to have multiple screen configuration:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

After that I enabled Unity driver in Compiz configuration. You can start Compiz configuration bay calling `ccsm` in a console.