# 14.04 LTS | Log Files | Debugging Unity, Gnome, XSession

Tags: unity, gnome

I'm unable to fix my Ubuntu desktop (GUI only). See:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/481788/14-04-lts-unity-reset-but-cant-login-normally

[14.04 LTS No Dash / Launcher after update through Software Updater](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477110/14-04-lts-no-dash-launcher-after-update-through-software-updater)

The issue is in the areas of Unity / Gnome / Xsession.

How should I debug? Which are the useful log files I can look into and post to this forum for help?

Comment: In /var/log are saved many log file, try to look syslog, dmesg and kern.log that are files where kernel print several information