# Launcher disappeared

Tags: 14.04, unity

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04. It worked for approx. 2 days. But today when I turned it on launcher & Menu bar was absent & ctrl+alt+t was also not working.
I tried "sudo service lightdm restart" it didn't worked. Please help me..
and launcher is present in guest session but not in Admin login..

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears.

Answer (score 5):

If above command doesnot work try this(it saved me a week ago):
`Ctrl+Alt+F1´

`sudo service lightdm stop
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
sudo service lightdm start`

Further look here: 
[14.04 LTS No Dash / Launcher after update through Software Updater](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477110/14-04-lts-no-dash-launcher-after-update-through-software-updater)

Comment: This deletes all your unity settings, including wallpaper, unity bar shortcuts, ...!

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many different things, but below solution worked for me:

- Go to your folder: usr/bin and click "gnome-terminal".
- When terminal opens write "ccsm"
- This will open unity screen.
- Select "unity plugin" and then tick "enable unity plugin" option.
- That will bring back your dashboard.

Comment: I tried this, but nothing happens, and after I close ccsm and reopen it, none of the settings seemed to stay there.

Comment: Yeah, re-login and set the mode to 'unity' is the key step.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following commands:-

```
Ctrl+Alt+F1
```

login there by user name and password, type

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

If lightdm fails to get back at normal :-
Enter:- `sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```