# No launcher and menu bar on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher, compiz

There is no launcher, menu bar and dash on my ubuntu 16.04. Happened when I logged in. Didn't do any changes to the system on my previous session. 16.04 has been working fine for me since it was released.

I know this has been answered before and I tried these answers:

[Launcher, menubar and window borders disappeared in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759150/launcher-menubar-and-window-borders-disappeared-in-ubuntu-16-04)

[Launcher disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656862/launcher-disappeared?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I first did a reset of .config/dconf but that didn't do it.

Edit:

Reinstalled Unity - no success
Disabled/Enabled Unity-plugin in Compiz-config-settings manager - no success

The icon for the Unity plugin in Compiz-config-settings manager looks like a question mark. Doesn't seem to look like that when I google images of the settings manager. Guess something is wrong with the plugin.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem. Out of the blue the launcher, menu bar and window had disappeared. Other users of the same installation had no problems, so it had to be a user configuration problem. I tried several of the mentioned solutions, but only this one worked:

```
mv ~/.cache/compizconfig-1 ~/.cache/compizconfig-renamed
shutdown -r 0
```

After that the controls came back after logging in and I resized the buttons in the launcher again.

Comment: it helped me!  thx

Comment: This saved my day. Any idea why this has happened in the first place???  Any update cause this???

Comment: Can confirm that none of the solutions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761035/ubuntu-16-04-no-menu-bar-or-launcher-help), [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04), or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) worked, but this solution did.

Comment: Thanks,its working perfect and prevent us to format the system :)

Comment: This fixed it for me too.

Comment: It helped me for my jetson TX2 ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried reinstalling Unity?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Tried that without success. I also enabled/disabled the unity plugin compiz-config-settings-manager without sucess.

Comment: Seems that the unity plugin doesn't work.  The unity plugin icon in compiz-config settings manager looks like a question mark. When I write unity in a terminal I can see the menubar flickering on top before it dissapears again. (The above of-course means that I managed to install compiz-config-settings manager).

Comment: Win's method worked for me

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

`compiz-settings` may do some desktop launcher disappearance **with or without changing system settings**, specially when you enable some cube engines that requires to disable some general requirements for your desktop environment.

meaning maybe there is no error , just edited configurations.

note : 
sometimes it happens when you suddenly shutdown your system.

1. can you provide us with your `xorg` and `xserver` in the user `home` log ?
2. run Ubuntu 16.04 `terminal` and run `compiz-settings` :

`right-click` on desktop + `open terminal`

then write in terminal :

`ccsm`

try to disable what you did and let us know please.

hints : in `ccsms` goto :

1. desktop -> enable Ubuntu unity plugins
2. uncategorized -> enable unity grab handles