# Launcher, menubar, toppanel and window borders disappeared in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: launcher

I tried all the stuff available in the following links.

[Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears/286444#286444)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2278870

[Unity Launcher and Top Panel disappeared in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04)

[Launcher, menubar and window borders disappeared in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759150/launcher-menubar-and-window-borders-disappeared-in-ubuntu-16-04)

[Launcher disappeared](https://askubuntu.com/questions/656862/launcher-disappeared)

But to my bad, nothing worked.

using ccsm, I enabled unity plugin.
once i close the ccsm and open again, I am seeing it is uncheck again.

Could some one help ?

Answer (score -1):

I have stumbled upon the exact same issue! I upgraded from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS about a month ago, and everything went very well. Recently, however, no dash or window border anymore!

I have tried, as suggested in several posts, to reset config:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

I tried to reinstall unity and compiz,

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge ubuntu-desktop compiz* unity*
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop compiz unity
```

I have tried to remove config files from local user hidden dirs,

```
sudo service lightdm stop
rm ~/.config/dconf/user
rm -fr ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
rm -fr ~/.compiz
rm -fr ~/.Xauthority
rm -fr ~/.config/autostart
sudo service lightdm start
```

Similarly, I enabled the Unity plugin in CCSM but this is not permanent since, when re-opening CCSM, the Unity plugin appears unchecked, even when opened with admin. rights.

Sadly, all of these attempts failed in restoring dash and window borders. I guess this is an issue with compiz, the window manager, but I have no idea how to fix it. Any ideas welcome ;)

Comment: this is not a answer.