# Dual Monitor not working - How to install Nvidia driver for 2 graphic card - GT630 and GT610?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

RESOLVED!! Ubuntu 16.04:

In software additional driver, For `GT630 - Nvidia-340` is the driver available and for `GT610 - Nvidia-304` is available. Installing one of them doesn't work out for both monitors. I wonder if I can install both and specify which driver to use for that specific device because:

**SOLVED** I'll reply with working copy of xorg.conf. I kinda messed up something else after it was resolved. Trying to fix [this issue now](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759150/launcher-menubar-and-window-borders-disappeared-in-ubuntu-16-04). Have backed up working copy of Xorg.conf.

**1)** If I install **`Nvidia-340`** it only works for first monitor, second monitor has no display. If `Xinerma` is enabled, secondary monitor has `Ubuntu Logo` in the center and mouse can be moved. But window can't be moved and no menu bar.

xorg.0.log:

```
  nvidia-1 : No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
  nvidia-1 : This device may have been added with another device file.
```

Nouveau is being used for GT610 by default.

If I `blacklist-nouevea`, reboot, then rather than Ubuntu Logo, it is just a black screen and I can move my mouse on that monitor (X cursor).

**2)** If I install **`Nvidia-304`** and restart then low graphic memory error and I will have to press alt+shift+f1 and purge `nvidia-304` to get display back.

I guess nvidia-304 would not work for GT630 and nvidia-340 won't work for GT610? And both can't have 2 different drivers????

Screen 1 - GT630

Screen 2 - GT610

Once I enable Xinerma, I can't access display properties (Xrandr extension not present). So I go to `nvidia-settings` and In `X Server settings`, both display are enabled and in `X Screen 0` options both GPU listed).  Should there be a X Screen 1, with GPU as GT610 right?

**UPDATE:** I can see `X Screen 1` in `nvidia-settings` after I rebuilt Xorg.conf and now in lock window, if I mouse hover to secondary monitor, login prompt switches to secondary monitor. I can login too.  But still there is a problem....

**Ubuntu Logo is finally gone** but no MENU bar and the default background is on top of everything?. I can move the window to next monitor but I can't see it. Its behind the default background.. If I can predict, I can drag the window back to screen 1. If I change wallpaper, it is only visible in Monitor 1 unless I restart lightdm, still a stuck background btw.

Please someone suggest me something,.. Kinda getting close to fix this. Just so you know this is the second time I'm installing Ubuntu in the last 3 months to try and fix it once and for all. I need to get it up during this weekend, if not - switch Nouveau drivers or Switch to Windows.

How I rebuilt xorg? : I opened `nvidia-setting` and deleted xorg.conf and saved.

If I enable Base-Mosiac then secondary monitor will get disabled and will not be visible in `nvidia-setting`. I manually tried to turn on Base-Mosiac in xorgs.conf but still nothing on secondary monitor.

Closest I can get to is with 340 drives and Ubuntu Logo centered on secondary monitor.

**3)** I'd like mention that `nouveva` drivers work for dual monitor except that for First monitor, mouse always flicker.. like 1000 times in a minute when playing video, without video a couple of 100 times in a minute (still very annoying). It doesn't flicker on secondary monitor.

xorgs.conf - updated

```
Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
Option         "Xinerama" "1"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
Load           "dbe"
Load           "extmod"
Load           "type1"
Load           "freetype"
Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

# generated from default
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

# HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Samsung"
HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

# HorizSync source: unknown, VertRefresh source: unknown
Identifier     "Monitor1"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Samsung"
HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 630"
BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device1"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 610"
BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-0"
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
# Removed Option "BaseMosaic" "on"
Identifier     "Screen1"
Device         "Device1"
Monitor        "Monitor1"
DefaultDepth    24
Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
Option         "Stereo" "0"
Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
Option         "SLI" "Off"
Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main change was just one line in xorg.conf. Both cards are using `Nvidia-340` driver now because `nouevea` is blacklisted.

```
Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
Changed as
Screen      1  "Screen1" 1440 0
```

Then make it read-only so during reboot it doesn't get changed: **`chmod 440 /etc/X11/xorg.conf`**

That got my second display working. If that is not the case, Check which PCI slot (lshw) of your primary monitor and  try flipping the bus ID and BoardName. OR rather rebuild xorg.conf. Just open `nvidia-setting` and then delete `xorg.conf` and click save in `nvidia-setting`

```
Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 610" <- before it was 630
BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"      <- before it was 1:0:0

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device1"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
BoardName      "GeForce GT 630"
BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
```

Its all about xorg.conf. Play with it and it should work. In case if your theme/unity window gets messed up, follow these steps.

Steps:

1. Press ctrl + alt + f1
2. sudo service lightdm stop
3. rm ~/.config/dconf/user
4. sudo service lightdm start