# Cannot enable Unity Plugin in ccsm

Tags: unity, 16.04, desktop-environments, display-manager, ccsm

I've tried enabling the Unity Plugin as described in this answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/717860/235839) (and several others).

Nothing changes.

When I try it again, I find that the plugin's checkbox isn't enabled. Apparently it un-enables it immediately after closing ccsm.

Is there some other way to enable the Unity Plugin--a command-line sequnce I could follow, perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

I encountered a similar problem today and none of the usual fixes were working for me either.

I eventually was able to resolve it by right clicking on the desktop then clicking on "Open Terminal" then used the following command:

```
mv ~/.cache/compizconfig-1 ~/.cache/compizconfig-OLD
```

After doing that just simply typing the following brought the full unity desktop back:

```
setsid unity
```

Hopefully this might help you or other users suffering similar symptoms, seems there was some issue with the compizconfig cache perhaps a file became corrupted somehow not certain.

Comment: Awesome, this totally worked! I got this error on my Ubuntu 16.04 after updating Unity to 7.4.5 by doing a `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Thank you I have been searching for 2 hours for a solution and this one finally worked!!! This bug happened for me after `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` on Ubuntu 16.04.