# Ubuntu 14.04 No Dash No Menu on an User Account

Tags: 14.04, unity, launcher, unity-dash

So my ubuntu doesn't have dash and menu bar after I logged in. But when I create and logged in as another user or logged in as a guest, the dash and menu work normally. What do you think went wrong with mine?

I've searched and tried the following, but it doesn't work

[Unity Launcher and Top Panel disappeared in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-menu-bar-disappeared-in-14-04)

[No panels or menus after upgrading to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468204/no-panels-or-menus-after-upgrading-to-14-04)

[14.04 LTS No Dash / Launcher after update through Software Updater](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477110/14-04-lts-no-dash-launcher-after-update-through-software-updater)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this :

**Ctrl+Alt+F1** login there by user name and password

Just try this :

> sudo service lightdm restart

If lightdm fails to get back at normal,then Type:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
>
> sudo apt-get install unity

**Note : IT Will Terminate Your ACTIVE SESSION**

Comment: Well, I'd tried that before but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try this! This may help you! http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: yeah I've also tried that before but it didn't work. I think I'll just use another user and delete existing user. But first do you know how to migrate/merge one user files to another user files?