# How to migrate/merge files from one user to another user in same computer?

Tags: permissions, adduser

[Ubuntu 14.04 No Dash No Menu on an User Account](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659703/ubuntu-14-04-no-dash-no-menu-on-an-user-account/659709?noredirect=1#comment949639_659709)

^ This a follow up question

Since my problem can't be solved and I want to delete the user that got problem, I think I want to move all user files from a user to another user. Do you know how to it?

ps: all user have sudo privileges and the users are in the same computer

Answer (score 0):

Move all the files with `mv` or copy with `cp` (`man mv` or `man cp` to get the syntax right). You may have to be root (ie use sudo) to do it, depending on permissions. Then, once the move/copy is done, `sudo chown -R newuser:newuser <everything you moved>`.